# How can count words of a line and keep the id of the line with apache pig?

Tags: count, apache-pig, cpu-word

I have a file whith 2 columns, the first one with the id and the second on with a long text and I need to know how to count words for each id.
For example if I have these two rows:

```
id | line
(1,  This country is beautiful)
(2, I would love to have a cup of tea)

The answer I need is:
(1, 4)
(2, 9)
```

I have read a lot of comments about this but everyone keeps the total numbers of each word or the total number of words without keeping the id of the line.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
FOREACH row GENERATE
    id,
    COUNT(STRSPLITTOBAG(line, " "));
```

This should take each row, produce the needed ID field, and then split the text based on a delimeter (here a " " value) to a bag type, where the COUNT function counts the number of items in the bag.